# Import Eviews workfile into R

Tags: r, import, eviews

I have problem importing an Eviews workfile into R. I use the hexView package and I can get the time series data into R but I do not get the periods responding to the time series imported. (The periods is not stored as a timeseries object.)

I would not like to create an time series objects for the periods in the workfile to solve the problem.

If there is another way than using the hexView package to import the data and the responding periods it would be great.

Right now I use this simple code to read the data into R

```
d <- readEViews("testData.wf1", as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

[image: Picture of workfile]

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the file format link from the documentation http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/~cottrell/eviews_format/ and opening work files in a hexedit program seems to suggest that the format for dates at least has changed.

Answer (score 1):

This question motivated me to create an R package [EviewsR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EviewsR/index.html), which is available on CRAN.

Please follow the following steps in R:

```
install.packages("EviewsR")
library(EviewsR)
import("importedDataframe","testData")
eviews$importedDataframe # to access the imported dataframe in R
```

The package works with base R, R Markdown and Quarto.

I am currently updating the package to provide new features

I look forward to your feedback.